# How to make a 'ease out' on focus loss in CSS

Tags: html, css

Today when I was going to style my Register form I found something that didnt look very nice.
I make a `ease in` when the `<input>` is selected, but when they unselect the `<input>` tag it just goes back to normal. This looks quietly ugly!
So my question is how can i make a CSS `OnFocusLoss` script that `ease out` by width?
This is a demo of my script so far: [JS Fiddle: TechnicalCoder/ease.css](https://jsfiddle.net/TechnicalCoder/0bzts2ua/).

```
input[type=text] {width:150px;height:50px;border: 2px solid;border-color: #e6e6e6;border-radius: 5px;color: #cccccc;padding: 3px;font-size: 30px;}
input[type=text]:focus {-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;-moz-transition: all .5s ease;transition: all .5s ease;width:700px;}
```

Now if you enter this link, then click on the input field then you will see it eases in... But if you click somewhere else on the page then it goes right back...
How can i make it ease backwards???
Thank you for taking time to help me out..
TechnicalCoder
EDIT:
Now i know how to do this! So the ting was i had to put the transition into the `input[type=text]` and then it eases back, heres an example:

```
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email] {width:150px;height:50px;border: 2px solid;border-color: #e6e6e6;border-radius: 5px;color: #cccccc;padding: 3px;font-size: 30px;font-family: SansaRegular;-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;-moz-transition: all .5s ease;transition: all .5s ease;}
input[type=text]:focus {-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;-moz-transition: all .5s ease;transition: all .5s ease;width:700px;}
```

You can find this script here: [JS Fiddle: TechnicalCoder/ease.css?update](https://jsfiddle.net/TechnicalCoder/1n5owq1w/).
Thanks for all the help!
Have a nice day!
TechnicalCoder

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Are you wanting pure CSS, or will a JavaScript function work?

Comment: A pure CSS @ShiningLight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, add the ease you had on your :focus input on the normal input in your css:

```
input[type=text] {width:150px;height:50px;border: 2px solid;border-color: #e6e6e6;border-radius: 5px;color: #cccccc;padding: 3px;font-size: 30px; -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;-moz-transition: all .5s ease;transition: all .5s ease;}

input[type=text]:focus {-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;-moz-transition: all .5s ease;transition: all .5s ease;width:700px;}
```

working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0bzts2ua/2/

Comment: You're very welcome, feel free to set it as the answer.